# Vector format export for screenshots

Tags: paraview

How to best export Scene/Screenshot in Paraview as a vector graphic?

It seems PDF and PS export are not working really good for me (Paraview 5.3/5.5/5.8), either the scene is cropped at the borders or text is missing (legends).

Answer (score 4):

Exporting to vector formats from ParaView is tricky, I have done it in the past but it depends on external dependencies (GL2PS, I think). For that I suggest you check the post in [ParaView Discourse](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/color-legend-location-changes-in-the-exported-pdf-or-eps-file/994).

On the other I would not recommend to have vector graphics for 3D visualizations. The size of the files get huge really fast and having a document with a couple of these files might be a nightmare. This was discussed already in a previous [answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/23148/9667).

Comment: I'd only export 2D views of my scene.

Comment: @stephanmg, I was also referring to 2D views of your scene. In general you get several lines/patches and the files are huge.

Comment: I see, yes, well, I just like to have the same font everywhere. It's okay to save screenshots from Paraview, but then the font is (in general) inconsistent of course.

Comment: you can use version 3.98 which should be able to export as svg. In newer version I do not know how to get svg images